# Can a query still use an index to sort a field if the index was not the one chosen in the winning plan?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I have a compound index and an index on a single field `A`. If in a find query, the compound index was chosen as the winning plan, and the results are sorted by the field `A`, will field `A`'s index be used to sort it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

MongoDB cannot use different indexes for sorting and document selection.

See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results

Note that it can use a compound index for sorting, i.e. if the compound index were on `{a:1, otherfield:1}`, that index can be used for selection by multiple fields, and sorting by `a`.